# Can't get polybar to display certain modules, when using xrandr --same-as function

Tags: shell-script

I am using the folowing script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Launch polybar (depending on multiple monitors or not)
if type "xrandr"; then 
    for m in $(xrandr --query | grep " connected" | cut -d" " -f1); do
        MONITOR=$m polybar --reload top &
        MONITOR=$m polybar --reload bottom & 
    done
else
    polybar top &
    polybar bottom &
fi
```

I want polybar to display the bars on each connected monitor and when duplicating the main screen, it has to show backlight/workspaces of the main display.